# Multiple Counts on different tables - Help me be more proficient

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to be a better query writer. I have a query that uses a few sub selects to get counts of different tables on my database. I am not sure its the most efficient method. I tried to use a LEFT JOIN to make it work better but it isn't coming up with the correct results.

Here is the 'working' query:

```
Select orgID,
(SELECT COUNT(recordID) FROM adoption WHERE orgID = 10031 
AND adoptDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19') as adoptTotal,
(SELECT COUNT(petID) FROM pets WHERE orgID = 10031
AND intakeDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19') as intakeTotal,
(SELECT COUNT(appID) FROM applications WHERE orgID = 10031 
AND applyDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19') as appTotal,
(SELECT COUNT(appID) FROM `ifosterpets`.`apps`WHERE orgID = 10031 
AND dateAdded BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19' and isactive = 1) as fosterApps,
(SELECT COUNT(matchID) FROM petmatches WHERE orgID = 10031
AND dateAdded BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19' AND isActive = 1) as matchTotals
FROM `memberships`.`orgs`
WHERE orgID = 10031
```

Here is what I tried that is getting the wrong results:

```
SELECT COUNT(ad.recordID) as adoptTotal, COUNT(p.petID) as intakeTotal, COUNT(a.appID) as appTotal, COUNT(f.appID) as fosterApps, COUNT(m.matchID) as matchTotals
FROM `memberships`.`orgs` o LEFT JOIN adoption ad ON ad.orgID = o.orgID
LEFT JOIN pets p ON p.orgID = o.orgID
LEFT JOIN applications a ON a.orgID = o.orgID
LEFT JOIN `ifosterpets`.`apps` f ON f.orgID = o.orgID
LEFT JOIN petmatches m ON m.orgID = o.orgID
WHERE ad.adoptDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19'
AND p.intakeDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19'
AND a.applyDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19'
AND f.dateAdded BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19'
and f.isactive = 1
AND m.dateAdded BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19' 
AND m.isActive = 1
AND o.orgID = 10031
```

This is a two part question: 1) What am I doing wrong on the LEFT JOIN query ? 2.) What is the most effiencient method to accomplish the first query results? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong on the `LEFT JOIN` query?

Recall that joins produce *cartesian products* of records, or simply speaking, the resultant rows contain combinations of data from the tables being connected through the join. When two tables in a join are related, the number of such combinations equals the number of rows matching the join condition. That's the "normal course of events".

However, when tables are unrelated, SQL produces all possible combinations of their rows. The number of such combinations grows as the product of row counts of individual tables.

Consider an example where you join table `A` to tables `B` and `C`, where `A` is related to `B` and `A` is related to `C`, but `B` and `C` are unrelated. If `A`'s join with `B` produces 10 records, and `A`'s join with `C` produces 5 records, `A`'s join to `B` and `C` together would produce 50 records. If you add table `D` with 6 rows in a join to `A`, the four-table join would produce 300 records. I hope you see the picture: when you shouldn't add tables unrelated to each other to a join, the number of results grows very fast.

> What is the most efficient method to accomplish the first query results?

There's nothing wrong with your original query, except that you could drop the outer `SELECT`'s `FROM` clause, like this:

```
Select
    10031 as orgID
,   (SELECT COUNT(recordID) FROM adoption WHERE orgID = 10031 AND adoptDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19') as adoptTotal
,   (SELECT COUNT(petID) FROM pets WHERE orgID = 10031 AND intakeDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19') as intakeTotal
,   (SELECT COUNT(appID) FROM applications WHERE orgID = 10031 AND applyDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19') as appTotal
,   (SELECT COUNT(appID) FROM `ifosterpets`.`apps`WHERE orgID = 10031 AND dateAdded BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19' and isactive = 1) as fosterApps
,   (SELECT COUNT(matchID) FROM petmatches WHERE orgID = 10031 AND dateAdded BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-10-19' AND isActive = 1) as matchTotals
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your using the left join u will get **duplicate** ids. so use **distinct** in the query

Ex as below:

```
select  COUNT(distinct t1.id),
        COUNT(distinct t2.tbl2id),
        COUNT( distinct t3.tbl3id) 
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.orgid = t2.orgid 
left join table3 t3 on t1.orgid = t3.orgid 
where t1.orgid = 1
```

I hope this will help you.